# HTML API callback doesn't work

Tags: clickatell

I tried to send sms via the HTML API and I would like to use the callback function, but clickatell doesn't call the entered URL.

I could send via this URL and I recived the sms `https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=_API_KEY_&to=_PHONE_NUMBER_&content=Test+message+text&callback=1`

`SMS Integration \ Settings \ Enable delivery notifications` is enabled and I entered the url in this format: `http://domain.co.uk/sms/status`. I tried the POST and GET method too.

When I enter this url to the address bar than this is works fine.

I read the documentation and I found the question from 2015 on stackoverflow, but this is a new API, I didn't found any other settings for callback url. I tired the parameter named callback with multiple value, but this didn't worked.

When I didn't found more settings I activated this integration, but I didn't found any difference.

Have somebody any idea?

Comment: Want to send sms using html ?

Comment: I could send sms from php via Clickatell, but the delivery notification doesn't works.